# How to trigger the address detection in mobile Safari HTML Documents?

Tags: html, ios, mobile-safari

I want to create HTML Pages containing addresses that should be detected by the Mobile Safari automatically to allow a quick connection/linking to the address book (for example: to allow creating new address book entries)

I have tried several basic formats but did not yet found a working solution.

Is this even possible and if so, what format should an address have to be able to be detected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you can't. Please see the [Apple URL scheme on the Safari Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more information on what is supported.

But you can't cheat a bit by offering your visitors to get your Vcard file sent by email (The iOS mail app supports this).

There is a good article and interesting comments on [the Code Train blog](http://thecodetrain.co.uk/2009/11/adding-a-vcard-to-your-iphone-address-book-from-a-web-page/).

Michael

Comment: The email alternative is what I am already doing but was looking for real solution, no workaround. For some reasons I didn't find the documentation you linked when I was looking for it, thank you for linking! :-)